# Flipping effect for buttons (dressed as cards) in iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, flip

UPDATE:

The problem I have so far is that I have to touch the cards two times for them to flip on load. After they've flipped the first time they would turn on touch as expected, but that first time the cards need two touches to the initial change of state.

Here's a little video to show the behavior I have just explained: http://youtu.be/KrCmfyK3Z9Q?hd=1

The code is pretty simple.  It goes like this:

Initialization on viwDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view addSubview:optionOneBack];        
    [self.view addSubview:optionTwoBack];        
    [self.view addSubview:optionThreeBack];  
}
```

Flip method:

```
- (void)flip:(id)sender {

    // Identify the card that has been touched (button clicked) and assign the values for the animation
if ((sender == optionOneFront) || (sender == optionOneBack)){
    front = optionOneFront;
    back  = optionOneBack;    
}
else if ((sender == optionTwoFront) || (sender == optionTwoBack)){ 
    front = optionTwoFront;
    back  = optionTwoBack;
}
else {
    front = optionThreeFront;
    back  = optionThreeBack;
}     

// Flip the card with animation
BOOL optionFrontIsHidden = front.hidden;

UIView *transitionView;
transitionView = optionFrontIsHidden ? back : front;

[UIView transitionWithView:transitionView
                  duration:0.5 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:nil
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    front.hidden = !optionFrontIsHidden;
                    back.hidden  = optionFrontIsHidden;
                }
];

}
```

---

Any help you can provide while I continue my googling would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advanced,

Juan.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

What you can do with `UIView`s can also be done with `UIButton`s, since they are descendants of `UIView`s too. So your transition code should work with very little adaptation needed.

Comment: Hi, do you think you can take a look at this again? It almost done now but I'm missing a tiny thing to make it work correctly.  Thanks!